# Pass object to routes file used as middleware in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

When my application starts, an object is created that is used throughout the app in multiple files.  In my app.js file I am requiring several files that contain my routes. These routes need access to the object created in app.js so I'm trying to pass it to each of these files. An example of one of the files is below.

**test.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use('/api', router);

router.post('/testRoute', (req, res, next) => {
    if(globalVariable.abc) { //globalVariable is the variable created in app.js
        //do some logic
    }
    res.json({
        message: "Test Route Success"
    })    
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
const assessmentRoutes = require('./routes/test');
app.use(assessmentRoutes);
```

One way I've tried to get the variable passed in is wrapping the routes in test.js in a function that takes the variable like this.

```
module.exports = function(globalVariable) {
    router.post('/testRoute', (req, res, next) => {
    if(globalVariable.abc) { //globalVariable is the variable created in app.js
        //do some logic
    }
    res.json({
        message: "Test Route Success"
    })    
});
}
```

Then in app.js the require changes to:

```
const assessmentRoutes = require('./routes/assessments')(globalVariable);
```

When I do it this way I get errors starting the application like app.use() requires a middleware function.

How to I pass the object into my routes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Using the global object

One approach, [which I don't recommend](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad), is using the [`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) object:

**`app.js`**

```
const assessmentRoutes = require('./routes/test');

global.globalVariable = { abc: ... };

app.use(assessmentRoutes);
```

**`test.js`**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/testRoute', (req, res, next) => {

    if (globalVariable.abc) { ... }

    res.json({
        message: 'Test Route Success',
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

#### ✨ Export a function and pass in options

Another approach is to export a function where you can pass in that as a param, as you did. The problem is that you are not returning the router from that function, that you later need to use in `app.js`:

**`app.js`**

```
const assessmentRoutes = require('./routes/test');

app.use(assessmentRoutes({ abc: ... }));
```

**`test.js`**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(globalVariable) {

    router.post('/testRoute', (req, res, next) => {

        if (globalVariable.abc) { ... }

        res.json({
            message: 'Test Route Success',
        });
    });

    //  This is what you were missing in your code!
    return router;
};
```

#### ✨ Export the router and a setter function

A similar option would be to export the `router` object as well as a setter function to initialise `globalVariable` inside `test.js`:

**`app.js`**

```
const { assessmentRoutes, initAssessmentRoutes } = require('./routes/test');

initAssessmentRoutes({ abc: ... });

app.use(assessmentRoutes);
```

**`test.js`**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

let globalVariable = { abc: null };

function initAssessmentRoutes(options) {
    globalVariable = options;
}

router.post('/testRoute', (req, res, next) => {

    if (globalVariable.abc) { ... }

    res.json({
        message: 'Test Route Success',
    });
});

module.exports = {
    assessmentRoutes: router,
    initAssessmentRoutes,
};
```

Comment: You are correct.  The missing return statement was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

APP.JS

```
 app.locals.globalVariable= {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
```

TEST.JS

```
if (req.app.locals.globalVariable.type =="Fiat" ) {
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test.js get rid of:

```
router.use('/api', router);
```

In your app.js change this line:

```
app.use('/', assessmentRoutes);
```

This should works.

Comment: How would test.js have access to globalVariable from app.js?

Comment: In test.js you're getting router form express.Route(), this has nothing to do with app.js then you export router which is imported into app.js where you should use it as I mentioned before.